# How to withdraw SOL from a PDA

Tags: anchor, rust, pda

I want to use my pda as a vault.

Deposit function works fine, but withdraw doesn't

```
    pub fn withdraw(ctx: Context<DepositWithdrawVault>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let config = &mut ctx.accounts.config;
        let recipient = &mut ctx.accounts.user;

        if transfer_amount > config.balance {
            return Err(errors::InsufficientBalance.into())
        }

        let transfer_sol = transfer( &config.key(), &recipient.key(), amount);
        let required_accounts_for_transfer = [
          config.to_account_info().clone(), 
          recipient.to_account_info().clone(), 
          ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info().clone()
        ];

        invoke(
            &transfer_sol,
            &required_accounts_for_transfer,
        )?;
        
        config.balance -= transfer_amount;
        Ok(())

        // another solution is:
        //    // Debit from_account and credit to_account
        // **from_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount_of_lamports;
        // **to_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount_of_lamports;
        // but how to modify it?
    }
```

and the test

```
initialize seed, bump and all that stuff

        await program.methods.withdraw(1)
            .accounts({
                user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                config: config,
                systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            }).rpc();
```

essentially, the error:

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4480:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4439:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:288:21)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:148:14)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
```

Comment: Please share the error that you get

Comment: my mistake, apologies for that. Just edited, please have a look :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @Ademola, here is the answer:

```
**ctx.accounts.config.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount;
**ctx.accounts.user.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount;
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to withdraw SOL from any account, the owner of the account needs to sign.

The result should look something like this:

```
let seeds = &[
    b"escrow".as_ref(),
    &[ctx.bumps.get("escrow")],
];
let signer = &[&seeds[..]];
let ix = anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
    &ctx.accounts.escrow.key,
    &ctx.accounts.destination.key,
    amount,
);
anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
    &ix,
    &[
        ctx.accounts.escrow.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.destination.to_account_info(),
    ],
    signer,
)?;
```

In this example, the `escrow` account is a PDA. Using the seeds and bump used to create the PDA, its signing seeds are recreated and used on the transfer instruction.

Comment: this only works if the PDA is owned by the system program, which does not appear to be OP's case

Comment: Could you please explain a way to make a transaction then, I found this article:

https://solanacookbook.com/references/programs.html#how-to-transfer-sol-in-a-program

"The fundamental rule is that your program can transfer lamports from any account owned by your program to any account at all."

Also, there is invoke_signed() function, but I am not sure how to pass seeds there as a signature, if anyone could help with that would be awesome!

Comment: Here's a link to a similar issue. You don't need signer seeds when the account is owned by your program and not the system program. https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/293/error-signature-verification-failed-when-using-pda-when-transfering-sol-from?rq=1

Comment: public key + b"VAULT"

Comment: Check out the link. I think it has your answer

Answer (score 0):

Before you withdraw, you need to add an if statement to make sure you have enough funds to withdraw and pay for the rent:

```
let config = &mut ctx.accounts.config;
let rent_due=Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(config.to_account_info().data_len());
```

then add the if statement

```
if **config.to_account_info().lamports.borrow()-rent_due<amount{
        return Err(ProgramError::InsufficientFunds);
    }
```

After you pass the guard:

```
  **config.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()?-=amount;
  **recipient.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()?+=amount;
```